# Why does the next button take so long to be pressed?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation

Ok quite simply I have a selenium script in C# and you choose a name from the dropdown box, choose the dates and counts the number of results page by page.  Now can someone help me speed this process because it almost takes 5 seconds for the next button to be clicked to go on the next page.

Here is my code:

```
int entityCount = 0;
int totalCount = 0;

try
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    while (_AuditRep.nextButton.Enabled && _AuditRep.nextButton.Displayed)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        _AuditRep.nextButton.Click();
        entityCount += _AuditRep.AuditResultsByEntity("Users").Count;
        totalCount += _AuditRep.AuditTotalResults.Count;

    }
    if (entityCount != totalCount)
    {
        Assert.Fail("The count of Drivers is " + entityCount + " whereas "
            + "the total count is " + totalCount);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The count of entity Drivers is " + entityCount + " and "
            + "the total count is " + totalCount);
    }
}
catch
{
    if (_AuditRep.AuditResultsByEntity("Users").Count != _AuditRep.AuditTotalResults.Count)
    {
        Assert.Fail("The count of Drivers is " + _AuditRep.AuditResultsByEntity("Users").Count + " whereas "
            + "the total count is " + _AuditRep.AuditTotalResults.Count);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The count of entity Drivers is " + _AuditRep.AuditResultsByEntity("Users").Count + " and "
            + "the total count is " + _AuditRep.AuditTotalResults.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I have just spotted my own problem I am putting a wait time of 5 secs for each click of the next button! doh! sorry but if anyone had any further suggestions how I can improve this code this would greatly be appreciated

Comment: You are sleeping the `UI` thread which results in messages not being pumped and delayed... What are you expecting to happen when you do this? Also I assume your while statement, `while(_AuditRep.nextButton.Enabled && _AuditRep.nextButton.Displayed)` something else is happening that would change the states? If not, why the loop?

Comment: The `while (_AuditRep.nextButton.Enabled && _AuditRep.nextButton.Displayed)` is there to check if the next button is available.  If its not there it stops paginating.  As a newbie, are you saying I don't need no threads whatsoever?  Sorry @Çöđěxěŕ I don't understand the comment about changing the states?

Comment: `are you saying I don't need no threads whatsoever`, No you don't and you are only working with one thread, that's the UI thread.